# logstash gork filter error : fetched an invalid config

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm using Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana to have an overview of my glassfish log file.

Do you know what wrong with my Logstash filter config?

my filter config look like that:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message", "(?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]" }
      add_field => [ "Log level", "%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}" ]
    }
  }
syslog_pri { }
date {
  match => {[ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]}
  }
}
```

When i start filebeat 5.0

```
sudo ./filebeat -e -c filebeat-logstash.yml -d "publish

ERR Failed to publish events caused by: EOF
2016/11/11 14:53:54.397825 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): EOF
2016/11/11 14:54:09.232146 logp.go:230: INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s:     filebeat.harvester.open_files=1 libbeat.logstash.call_count.PublishEvents=5 libbeat.logstash.publish.read_errors=5 libbeat.logstash.publish.write_bytes=5542 libbeat.publisher.published_events=2047 filebeat.harvester.running=1 libbeat.logstash.published_but_not_acked_events=10235 filebeat.harvester.started=1
```

Logstash log

http://pastebin.com/Hh9ECFjd

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-11-11T14:40:35.247000+0000", :message=>"fetched an invalid config", :config=>"input {\n  lumberjack {\n    port => 5000\n    type => \"log\"\n    ssl => false\n    #ssl_certificate => \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt\"\n    #ssl_key => \"/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key\"\n  }\n}\n\ninput {\n  beats {\n   port => 5044\n   ssl => false\n   # ssl_certificate => \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-beats.crt\"\n   # ssl_key => \"/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-beats.key\"\n  }\n}\n\nfilter {\n  if [type] == \"log\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\", \"(?m)\\[\\#\\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\|%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}\\|%{DATA:server_version}\\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\\|%{DATA:thread}\\|%{DATA:message_detail}\\|\\#\\]\" }\n      add_field => [ \"Log level\", \"%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}\" ]\n    }\n   }\n    syslog_pri { }\n    date {\n      match => {[ \"timestamp\", \"MMM  d HH:mm:ss\", \"MMM dd HH:mm:ss\" ]}\n   }\n}\n\n\nfilter {\n  if [type] == \"nginx-access\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\" => \"%{NGINXACCESS}\" }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"http://localhost:9200\"]\n    sniffing => true\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 23, column 27 (byte 461) after filter {\n  if [type] == \"log\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\"", :level=>:error}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your config.

```
grok {
  match => { "message", "(?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]" }
}
```

Don't use spaces in field names. The field to parse and the grokstring need an arrow `=>`. They are not supported. You also don't need to add the loglevel field because grok is doing that for you.

```
date {
  match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

You don't need curly brackets in the date match because it is expecting a array.

The [lumberjack input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html) requires you to use SSL you can't disable it with `ssl => false`. This however works for the beats input.

The full config will look like this:

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "log"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/foo.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/foo.key"
  }
}
input {
  beats {
   port => 5044
  ssl => false
    }
}
filter {
if [type] == "log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" =>  "(?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]" }
    }
  }
syslog_pri { }
date {
  match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd"
    document_type => "%[@metadata][type]"
  }
}
```

One more thing regarding debugging your config. You posted your logstash log and logstash itself is telling you what it can't interpret.

```
:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 23, column 27 (byte 461) after filter {
  if [type] == \"log\" {
    grok {
      match => { \"message\"", :level=>:error}
```

This way you are able to quickly find errors you might have missed.

Comment: Hi Fairy Thanks.
I used it now your edited filter config, but the same error. 
here is my complete config file http://pastebin.com/tGegZuec
:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 23, column 26 (byte 458) after filter {\nif [type] == \"log\" {\n    grok {\n      match => {\"message\"", :level=>:error}

What was the problems at all? I did not get yet.!

Comment: @zoram I updated my answer. I added the full fixed config which will run now. Not the grok match arrow and the lumberjack SSL.

Comment: Thanks! Now it work. 

But I can't see the data in KIBANA. I could get my index pattern "filebeat-*" in Kibana but, there are no Field to select.
logstash output: http://pastebin.com/awaCC580
filebeat output: http://pastebin.com/DsRswEdT

Comment: it work fine now. 
index => "filebeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" I changed the index pattern name as above.

Comment: @zoram Cool :) Don't forget to accept this answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I could gain a lot experiences with this post.